# How to check the order status of a binance order properly

Tags: python, api, python-requests, binance

I'm trying to create a sell order and then continuously checking if it has been fulfilled or not but after like one or two iterations in the loop it shows order status as filled whereas the order hasn't been filled actually or sometimes it says order does not exist.

Is there anything wrong with my code or is there a better way to do it?

```py
# SELL
try:
    #LIMITSELL

    client.order_limit_sell(symbol=pair,quantity=quantity,price=sellPrice)
    orderId=client.get_all_orders(symbol=pair,limit=1)[0]['orderId']
    print('Sell order placed at {}\n'.format(sellPrice))

    while True:
        openOrders = client.get_all_orders(symbol=pair,limit=1)[0]
        if openOrders['status']=='FILLED':
            print("Sold: {} at {}".format(quantity,sellPrice))
        
            exit(0)
        print(".")
```

I tried using the `orderId` as well by using `client.get_order(symbol=pair,orderId=orderId)` but it still does the same thing.

Comment: get_all_orders() returns a list of matching orders. some of them would already be filled and some not. you're taking randomly the first one. this could be an old order which is already filled. so you're not tracking the actual order that was created by order_limit_sell and that's why your loop bails out right away. I suggest to check what's the return value of order_limit_sell. maybe it's the actual orderId which you need to track.

Comment: @shauli I used client.create_order() this fxn returns the orderId but then afterwards checking inside the loop it does the same thing

Comment: is there a websocket version of this ?  ie.  when traded the websocket sends a message of the trade ?

Answer (score 7):

```
order = client.order_limit_sell(symbol=pair,quantity=quantity,price=sellPrice)
orderId = order["orderId"]
print('Sell order placed at {}\n'.format(sellPrice))
    while True:
        currentOrder = client.get_order(symbol=pair,orderId=orderId)
        if currentOrder['status']=='FILLED':
            print("Sold: {} at {}".format(quantity,sellPrice))
            break
        print(".")
```

A better way to do this is to create another Thread using built-in threading module in Python.